# Spring Integration Custom poller

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a custom poller for my spring integration workflow. Is there way to provide custom implementation on poller ? I need to change the max-messages-per-poll depending on my application current workload.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement bridge to customize max-messages-per-poll

```
<int:bridge input-channel="pollable" output-channel="subscribable">
 <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-rate="5000"/>
```